# Problema com envio de dados via ajax e laravel

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

Boa tarde, estou com problema para enviar dados via ajax, retorna o code 200 mas retorna

> SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Mas acredito que não chega nem no controller

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" onclick="inserirContato()" value="Inserir Contato">
<script>

function inserirContato() {

var cliente = document.getElementById('cliente_id').value;
var nome = document.getElementById('nome').value;
var departamento = document.getElementById('departamento').value;
var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
var telefone = document.getElementById('telefone').value;
var celular = document.getElementById('celular').value;


$.ajax({
    headers: {
            'X-CSRF-Token': $('input[name="_token"]').val()
        },
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "json",
    url: '{{ route('admin.cadastro.contatos.store') }}',
    data: {
        'contatable_id': cliente,
        'contatable_type' : "App\Cliente",
        'nome' : nome,
        'departamento' : departamento,
        'email' : email,
        'telefone' : telefone,
        'celular' : celular
    },
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(response, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(response);

    },
});
}
</script>
```

Comment: Em `'{{ route('admin.cadastro.contatos.store') }}'` acho que deve ser `"{{ route('admin.cadastro.contatos.store') }}"`, não? Tente trocar as aspas "externas" simples por duplas e vê se resolve...

Comment: Não resolveu...

Comment: Se você colocar `dataType: 'html'`, o que é retornado?

Comment: Continua não retornando nada

Comment: Há uma vírgula a mais depois da função `error`, remova ela e tente novamente. Só para esclarecer o que estou a fazer é que este tipo de erro ocorre apenas quando a estrutura de um JSON não está bem definida. Em algum local do seu código, onde está usando um JSON, não está escrito corretamente...

Comment: Resolvido, a rota apontava para o controller errado! Obrigado a todos!